# NSDictionary suddenly becomes an NSArray

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have this URL that returns JSON. I write the JSON to a Dictionary as follows:

```
NSData* Data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
NSDictionary *schools = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:Data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

Then, I write that Dictionary to a file:

```
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"schools.plist"];    
[schools writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

While running the code, I inspect the Dictionary, that appears to contain valid objects:

[image]

However, when I inspect the file on disk, it looks like an Array:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Id</key>
        <string>ffefe0f7-23bf-471f-8e99-58ada0229921</string>
        <key>Name</key>
```

Is that expected behavior? Other methods in my code rely on getting a Dictionary from that file.

Comment: `NSLog(@"Class: %@", [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:Data options:kNilOptions error:nil] class])` returns really a NSDictionary? Could it be that your JSON returns in fact a NSArray? Also, check if `schools` is not "overwritten" (reset) somewhere

Comment: It looks like `JSONObjectWithData` is returning an `NSArray` containing `NSDictionary`s.

Comment: See my added illustration. When 'schools' is initiated, is seems to have no issue with the json data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you declare your variable to be of type `NSDictionary` does not mean that the call to `JSONObjectWithData` is *really* returning an `NSDictionary`.

My guess is that the file you're getting from your server is really an array that contains a dictionary. Try logging the type of the object returned by `JSONObjectWithData` before you save it to a file:

```
NSDictionary *schools = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:Data 
  options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSLog(@"schools class = %@", [schools class]);
```

Comment: schools class = __NSCFArray. Indeed. Is there an easy way to turn it into a Dictionary?

Comment: @Sjakelien Why do you want to do that?

Comment: What I see in your data is an array that contains a single element, a dictionary. Just fetch that first element. That should be the dictionary you need.

Comment: thank you all. I got a bit confused. In the end it was pretty straight forward, but I somehow dogmatically thought that I needed a dictionary. The Array served me well.